# Updating values in ObservableCollection

Tags: wpf, listbox, updates, observablecollection

Hey I have an `ObservableCollection` which consists of a class with two attributes (strings = User and Response) bound to a `listbox`.

I would like to have the users in the listbox first, which I add with this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ArrStrUser.Length; i++)
{
  Users.Add(new User() { input = ArrStrUser[i].Trim() });              
}
```

I want to add the responses to the respective user later.
If I do this, they will be added to the ObservableCollection but not update in the listbox.

`Users[i].response = strOutput.Trim().Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ");`

The ObservableCollecton

`private ObservableCollection<Input> Users = new ObservableCollection<Input>();`

The Class:

```
public class Input
{
 public string user{ get; set; }
 public string response { get; set; }
}
```

XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="LBresponse" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource UserTemplate}" />

<DataTemplate x:Key="UserTemplate">
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path= user}" Width="50"/>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path= response}" />
    <Button Content="Delete" Click="DeleteUser_Clicked" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
  </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Simple solution

Your `Input` class needs to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and invoke the `PropertyChanged` event upon changing property's value in order to update the `ListBox`. The `ObservableCollection` only "cares" about adding or removing items, it doesn't handle item's property changing.

Try editing your input class like this:

```cs
public class Input : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string user{ get; set; }

    private string _response;
    public string Response{
        get => _response;
        set {
            _response = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
 
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Now changing the `Response` property should update the UI.

---

### Better solution

I'd also advise you to separate the `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation into its own class if you want to use it somewhere else, too. Or better yet, use a library that already has it, like the [mvvm-helpers nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Refractored.MvvmHelpers/) by James Montemagno.

Here's a link to the `INotifyPropertyChanged` [implementation from that library](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/mvvm-helpers/blob/master/MvvmHelpers/ObservableObject.cs)

This is how you use it:

```cs
public class Input : ObservableObject
{
    public string user{ get; set; }

    private string _response;
    public string Response{
        get => _response;
        set => SetProperty(ref _response, value);
    }
}
```

It also supports passing in an OnChanged `Action` and a validation function.